# docx2txt don't returns the page numbers

Tags: docx

There's any way to return the page numbers when using Python docx2txt to read a docx file in Python?

I'm using the following code to return the docx content but it only returns the raw text. For my application I also need the page numbers.

```
docx2txt.process
```

There is a way to get the page numbers with the content with docx2txt or using another lib?

Answer (score -1):

## Getting the page numbers of doc using Python libraries

**PyPDF2**

```
  import PyPDF2
  pdfFileObj = open('source.pdf', 'rb')
  pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
  print(pdfReader.numPages)
  #get totalnumber of pages and page numbering in PyPDF2 starts with 0
  pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
  pageObj.extractText()
  pdfFileObj.close()
```